# How to go through Ruby multidimensional list

Tags: ruby

How can I go through list like this by Ruby:

```
l = {}
l["account-id"] = "123"
l["account-id"] = {}
l["account-id"]["banana"] = {}
l["account-id"]["banana"]["good"] = "true"
l["account-id"]["banana"]["bad"] = "false"
l["account-id"]["apple"] = {}
l["account-id"]["apple"]["good"] = "false"
l["account-id"]["apple"]["bad"] = "true"
```

Basically, I want get pair like

```
"123" "banana" "true" "false"
"123" "apple" "true" "true"
```

How to get it? And is there any more efficient way to create this kind of list rather than using `= {}` to declare for every subset? In my case, there are many different `account-id`, and fruits like `apple` and `banana`, but the last one (`good` and `bad`) is fixed. Thank you.

Comment: The input is not a list, the output is not “pair-like.” Please start with putting some effort into stating the question. Also, `account_id` is dropped in the third line, hence the input data is not consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you do not generate the nested hash you think you do because the third line overwrites the value you assigned in the second:

```
l["account-id"] = "123"
l["account-id"] = {}
```

As a result, the returned hash does not include an account id anymore.

But there is an easier and more readable way to define the hash anyway:

```
l = {
  '123' => {
    'banana' => {
      'good' => 'true',
      'bad' => 'false'
    },
    'apple' => {
      'good' => 'false',
      'bad' => 'true'
    }
  }
}
```

To return your expected output I would do something like this:

```
l.flat_map { |id, fruits| fruits.map { |name, tastes| [id, name, *tastes.values] } }
#=> [["123", "banana", "true", "false"], ["123", "apple", "false", "true"]]
```

---

Some things I would improve about your data structure: The good/bad sub hash feels a bit weird to me because it is not clear how it should be used. Imagine someone enters `{ 'good' => 'true', 'bad' => 'true' }`, what does that mean. Furthermore, you store the `id` (what looks like an integer) and the booleans as strings. I would use their real data type.

```
l = {
  123 => {
    'banana' => {
      'likes' => true
    },
    'apple' => {
      'likes' => false
    }
  }
}
```

Or just:

```
l = {
  123 => {
    'banana' => true,
    'apple' => false
  }
}
```

But that depends on where the data is coming from and how you need the data to be structured afterwards.